# How can Color Histogram be performed on KNN to classify colors?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, feature-extraction, knn

General Topic: Color Matching Application by Feature Extraction with Classification

I decided to use "Color Histogram" and "K Nearest Neighbor" for classifying the colors.

I can get the image color histograms and I can deploy them in csv file with label to train KNN. This step is done! However, I can not figure out that how can send test image color histogram values to KNN for classifying it? There are a bunch of matrix values in test image color histogram. So my question is that how can send this point cloud (color histogram values of a test image) to KNN for classifying it?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert RGB color space to HSV color space and use Hue channel and their labels  as training input to KNN classifier function. Below is a simple implementation:

```
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(rgbimage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hue = hsv_img[:,:,:1].flatten()
```